# HTML CSS positioning images regardless of everything

Tags: html, css

I have this PHP HTML code. My question is how can I do that fourth picture's position doesn't change even if the third image is not displayed before it.
Here it is two pictures what I would:

**In case $randomnumber is 1:**

[image]

**In case $randomnumber is 0: (You can see that fourth picture's position doesnt changed.)**

[image]

```
<html>

<body>
<div>

<style>
.sarga1 {
  z-index: 5;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  left: 30px;
  top: 100px;
}

.extremewind1 {
  z-index: 5;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  left: 30px;
  top: 100px;
}

.sarga2 {
  z-index: 5;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  left: 30px;
  top: 100px;
}

.extremewind2 {
  z-index: 5;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  left: 10px;
  top: 100px;
}
</style>


<?php
echo '<div class="sarga1">', "<img src='sarga.png'>";
echo '<div class="extremewind1">', "<img src='extremewind.png'>";

$randomnumber = rand(0,1);
echo $randomnumber;

if ($randomnumber == 1)
   echo '<div class="sarga2">', "<img src='sarga.png'>";


echo '<div class="extremewind2">', "<img src='extremewind.png'>";

?>

<div>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: If I use on "sarga2" absolute positioning, still not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your divs in a div `position:relative`, and use `position:absolute` on the children. Example:

```css
.sarga1 {
  z-index: 5;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0;
}

.extremewind1 {
  z-index: 5;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
}

.sarga2 {
  z-index: 5;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: 100px;
}

.extremewind2 {
  z-index: 5;
  position: absolute;
  left: 150px;
  top: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div style="position:relative">
  <div class="sarga1">Sarga1</div>
  <div class="extremewind1">Extreme Wind</div>
  <!--<div class="sarga2">Sarga 2</div>-->
  <div class="extremewind2">Extreme Wind</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of relative position, use absolute.

Comment: For each picture?

Comment: Just the one you want to stay in absolute spot and not depending on others.

Answer (score 0):

Update your CSS code as shown below.

```
.extremewind2 {
    z-index: 5;
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    left: 12%;
    bottom: 12%;
}
```

This will work for you. Try it.